# This error appeared when running the application on an Android mobile

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

**This error appeared when running the application on an Android mobile**

Launching lib\main.dart on DRA LX2 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install E:\flutter_projects\quizzler-flutter\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]
Error launching application on DRA LX2.

Answer (score 1):

It appears, you have insufficient storage to install the app on your phone:

> [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]

If you are sure you have enough free space, you can try uninstalling the app completely (for all users) and then retrying the installation.